# add files to subfolder inside zip when creating

Tags: bash, zip, subdirectory

I would like get the following on linux bash script:

zip file FILE1.jar into a new archive inside of a subdirectory.

given:
myfiletozip.jar

**expected:**

- ./myfiletozip.jar
- ./myarchive.zip

  - | /mods/
  - - |  /myfiletozip.jar

Is it possible to add a non existant path **during** creation?
Or do i have to create a temp way at filelevel before zipping?

Answer (score 0):

I have no memory of an option that allows you to create a zip file with non existent directory inside.

But with `php` you can create in advance the empty zip file with the empty non existent directory, and after you can update the file with the real files/structures you want.

Run first this script with `php myscript.php`

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open('my-archive.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
$zip->addEmptyDir('./dir1/subdirA');
$zip->addEmptyDir('./dir2/subdirB');
$zip->close();
?>
```

and after

```
zip -u my-archive.zip path_to_add
```